# mysql - Query by interval and or returning nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select only emails from the users table where the `weekly_mail` (datetime) is older that one week or null and if the user's points add up to more than 10. It's not returning anything now.

points_plus table structure

```
id | user_id | points | date
1    62        5        2015-05-13 08:42:37
2    62        15       2015-05-14 03:12:32
```

query

```
$q = "SELECT u.email, u.weekly_mail, SUM(p.points) AS points
      FROM users u
      LEFT JOIN points_plus p
      ON u.id = p.user_id
      WHERE points > 10 AND u.weekly_mail < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK OR u.weekly_mail = NULL
      GROUP BY p.user_id";
$result = $this->db->mysqli->query($q);

if (!$result) {
    printf("Query failed: %s\n", $this->db->mysqli->error);
    exit;
}

$rows = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $rows[]=$row;
}

$result->close();
return $rows;
```

Comment: you can't use the alias `points` in the `WHERE` clause because of the order in which the statement is executed, you should use `HAVING`

Comment: this condition `u.weekly_mail = NULL` would be `u.weekly_mail IS NULL`

Comment: u.weekly_mail is what I have in my query ... just a copy paste error there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
$q = "SELECT u.email, u.weekly_mail, SUM(p.points) AS points
      FROM users u
      LEFT JOIN points_plus p
      ON u.id = p.user_id
      WHERE u.weekly_mail < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) OR u.weekly_mail IS NULL
      GROUP BY p.user_id having SUM(p.points) > 10";
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT u.email, u.weekly_mail, SUM(p.points) AS points
  FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN points_plus p
   ON u.id = p.user_id
  WHERE u.weekly_mail < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK OR u.weekly_mail = NULL
  GROUP BY p.user_id having SUM(p.points) > 10
```

Comment: It still returns nothing